# Place an absolute element in bottom of a container with overflow: auto

Tags: html, css, position, absolute

I have a logo that should be positioned in the very bottom of a fixed container. It works OK with position: absolute; however if I add overflow-y: auto; to the fixed container and add content that doesn't fit the viewport height, my logo will stick to the bottom of the viewport, not the bottom of the fixed container, thus overlapping the content.

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="content"></div>
    <div class="logo-in-the-bottom">Logo</div>
</div>

.foo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.content {
    height: 1000px;
}
.logo-in-the-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; left: 0;
    color: white
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1aoah1r5/

**How do I stick it to the bottom of the fixed container no matter the content height?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

### Depending on content:

```css
.foo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.content {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}
.logo-in-the-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; left: 0;
    color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="logo-in-the-bottom">Logo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For future references:

### Sticky version:

```css
.foo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: gray;
}
.container {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.content {
    height: 1000px;
}
.logo-in-the-bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px; 
    left: 0;
    color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="content">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="logo-in-the-bottom">Logo</div>
</div>
```

You need to add an extra container with the overflow inside the `.foo`. Why ? That way the `.foo` is fixed and the absolute is relative to the fixed position, not the content because the `.container` is the one overflowing.

### On the bottom:

```css
.foo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: gray;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
.content {
    height: 1000px;
}
.logo-in-the-bottom {
    position: relative; //no need for absolute
    color: white
}
```

```html
<div class="foo">
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
      <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
        <div class="logo-in-the-bottom">Logo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It won't work because if the content is not enough the logo will not stick to the bottom of the page, it will go right after the content.

Comment: So you want it to be on bottom case there is no content and after all content if the content is too big ?

Comment: Check edit depending on content. Edit only the content height, not the `min-height`

Comment: Changed the last one to first one for future users, and left all the other for different situations.

Answer (score 0):

Put logo into `.content` (and add bottom padding to .content, if you need to make a space for logo).

```
<style>
.content {
    height: 1000px;
    position: relative;
}
</style>

<div class="foo">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="logo-in-the-bottom">Logo</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1aoah1r5/1/

Comment: It won't work because if the content is not enough the log0 will not stick to the bottom of the page, it will go right after the content.  http://jsfiddle.net/1aoah1r5/2/

Comment: @Deka87: okay, so http://jsfiddle.net/1aoah1r5/4/ vs. http://jsfiddle.net/1aoah1r5/5/. It should be what you need.